# Only run a particular app at startup if WiFi is connected

Tags: update-manager, startup-applications

I want to run an app on startup called Software Updater, Generally what I'd do is add it to the Startup apps list and It'd start up every time I boot. What I want to do instead is I want to run it only when WiFi is connected.

So basically

- Check for connected WiFi, if it's connected then Run *[Software Updater](https://launchpad.net/update-manager)*
- If it's not then don't do anything.

---

Saved WiFi's that are in range are automatically connected on boot.

Comment: How do you run this software updater? and how do you connect to your Wi-Fi (using Network Manager or ...)?

Comment: @Ravexina Software updater is an app bundled with Ubuntu Gnome. and I'm looking for automatically connected WiFi here, saved WiFi that are in range. and I generally use Gnome's top right menu to connect it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If using NetworkManager, you can put a script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` and have it "listen" for a wifi UP event. Note you may have to change the WLAN interface name

Here is an example:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

IFACE=$1 STATUS=$2
IW=/usr/bin/iw
WLAN_IFACE=wlp1s0

if [ ! -x $IW ]; then
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$IFACE" = $WLAN_IFACE ] && [ "$STATUS" = "up" ]; then
    echo "[SCRIPT] -- PUT SOMETHING HERE YOU WANT TO HIT LOGS --"
    echo "Replace this echo with a command line instruction"
fi
```

You could extend the above logic to only fire on a given Network, etc.

Here is a reference to NetworkManager events ($2) that may be helpful: https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html